# GitHub action fails on npm ci

Tags: github, npm, github-actions, npm-ci

I have git action to run prettier(Code formatter). Below is the `format.yml` file of git action.

```
name: Format code with prettier
on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - master
jobs:
  format:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # Install NPM dependencies, cache them correctly
      - name: Run prettier
        run: |
          npm ci
          npm run prettier-check
```

The error that I am getting is listed below.

```
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'react-lottie@1.2.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { npm: '^3.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.1.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
...
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/runner/work/Web/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /home/runner/work/Web/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/home/runner/work/Web/node_modules/node-sass/build'
npm ERR!   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/runner/.node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node -I/home/runner/.node-gyp/16.13.0/src -I/home/runner/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/config -I/home/runner/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/runner/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/uv/include -I/home/runner/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/zlib -I/home/runner/.node-gyp/16.13.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp
...
npm ERR! gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv/os390.h
npm ERR! gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv/posix.h
npm ERR! gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv/stdint-msvc2008.h
npm ERR! gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv/sunos.h
npm ERR! gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv/threadpool.h
npm ERR! gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv/unix.h
npm ERR! gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv/win.h
npm ERR! gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv/errno.h
npm ERR! gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv/tree.h
npm ERR!
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Git action `yml` file used to work before. I haven't changed any version/package-lock file. Still, it is failing. Can anyone suggest a solution from the error log?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you are running different node version in your githubAction.

Set up the same node version that you use local(e.g. 14) before to run `npm ci`:

```
- uses: actions/setup-node@v2
  with:
    node-version: '14'
- name: Run prettier
  run: |
    npm ci
    npm run prettier-check
...
```